# set up client to use local dns server in my local network

Tags: networking, dns

I have a quick question on how to set up the client to use the local dns server. I was able to successfully set up a local dns server in my network. I have two ubuntu computers in my network : 192.168.1.129 that is the dns server and it is set up correctly, while the client is 192.168.1.100.

ON the client : 192.168.1.100

etc/network/interface file has the following lines

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255 
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.129 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

while etc/resolv.conf has the the following lines

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.1.129
```

I can ping 192.168.1.129 (the dns server), if I do an nslookup 192.168.1.129 I have the following errors :

```
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53
** server can't find 129.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You should probably set up that in your DHCP server which then broadcast it to the clients while sending requests.

Comment: @AzkerM, thanks, but I your answer is too concise and I am not that expert in ubuntu, so if you wouldn't mind elaborate a little bit more, that would be really great !

Comment: For some reason 8.8.8.8 is taking precedence and becomes your primary dns so something else is changing  your /etc/resov.conf what do you expect to see when you do `nslookup 192.168.1.129` ? it goes out to your primary dns (which is 8.8.8.8) who obviously can't resolve local ip. try `nslookup 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.129`

Comment: @geppo you should approach either `resolv.conf` or `interfaces` to add in DNS entries. However, entries passed in `resolv.conf` aren't permanent as it will be cleared upon a system reboot. It seems you have added a static ip manually, and I would suggest you keep the DNS entries as `192.168.1.129 8.8.8.8` if required. Also would you please add in more details as what device or the server handles the DNS?

Comment: After doing some more searches, perhaps the reason it is not working because I have a LInksys Wireless Router that is acting as dhcp server. Maybe I should disable that and install dchp server on the linux dns server, so I have more control of the settings. BTW, if I remove 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 from dns-nameservers in the interface file of the ubuntu client, it cannot connect to the internet...what settings can I share about the ubuntu dns server ? Thanks to AzkerM and all the others that are replying to my questions - sorry it takes time since I can only work on my home network when I am home

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want the client (1.100) to use your server (1.129) as its primary DNS server.  The server should also know how to resolve additional addresses (eg forwarders), so in essence, it's the only DNS server than your client needs to know about.

Multiple guides available on setting up DNS/bind.  I've been partial to the guides from Digital Ocean as they are written for Ubuntu.  Look at the section to 'Configure Options File', specifically the part about forwarders.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: thanks ! I will check that out. You bring a good point that 1.100 should not know about other DNS than 1.129 since on 1.129, using bind, I configured the forwarders 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.

Comment: Not necessarily. It is always a good practice to use multiple DNS servers given that local DNS can go crashing and the system still requires a DNS that can resolve queries. Having that said, DNS server which is responsible for resolving should have forwarders which makes the processes faster in resolving global queries that are not internal.